# Delete Script Does not Delete rather it refreshes the page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I created a database where I store some pieces of data and display them on the HTML table, I put a delete button but when I run the script to delete it rather refreshes it

I don't know where it fails, and down here is my code of the table

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
            <tbody>
<?php 
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "blog", "0000", "blog");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM room_details ");

        echo "<tr>
                <th> Room Name</th>
                <th> Room No.</th>        
                <th> Type</th>
                <th> Price</th>
                <th> Action</th>
              </tr>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {

         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$row['room_name']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['room_number']."</td>";  
         echo "<td>".$row['room_type']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['room_price']."</td>";
         echo "<td>"?><div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" 
 href="incl/process.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">DELETE<i 
 class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
                  </div></td>
         <?php echo "</tr>";
 } ?>    
          </tbody>
          </table>
```

and this is delete processing code,

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "blog", "0000", "blog");
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM room_details WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
header("Refresh: 2; url=rooms.php");
echo '<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
              <strong>SUCCESS!!</strong> Data deleted!.
            </div>';
}

?>
```

It doesn't delete the row but now it hangs on process.php nothing is happening, where did I go wrong?

Comment: It refreshes the page because of  this `header ("Refresh: 2; url=rooms.php");`

Comment: Hp_issei i put that so it will redirect to rooms.php in two seconds but instead it run the process.php (where there's delete query) and it hangs there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from that you have to set the `$id` using `$id = $_GET['delete'];` instead of `$id = $_GET['id'];` because `delete` is what you are passing in the query string, the `prepare` method should be called on `$conn`.

Change this line:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM room_details WHERE id = ?");
```

To this line:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM room_details WHERE id = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why it's hanging, but you haven't set a variable called 'id'. Should be:

```
$id = $_GET['delete'];
```